# php Embedding single quote within double quotes won't work

Tags: php

Please help. I'm really stuck on this and I'm learning PHP. I know the basics but I need to learn advance things like below:

```
echo "<code><p></code>$_POST[quiz_complete]<code></p></code>"; //this code won't execute
//Note: variable $_POST['quiz_complete'] exists
<code>echo "<p>$str</p>";</code> //works fine
```

This ' single quotes don't work. How do I get single quotes to work within a variable that's inside double quotes for eg)

```
echo "<code>&lt;p&gt;</code>$_POST['quiz_complete']<code>&lt;p&gt;</code>";
```

Comment: `"<p>{$_POST['quiz_complete']}</p>"`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "<p>{$_POST['quiz_complete']}</p>"
```

or I would actually prefer

```
echo '<p>' . $_POST['quiz_complete'] . '</p>'
```

Syntax highlighting will make it much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question with {. :)

Comment: Cool, where is there documentation on embedding { tags within a string for php? I can't find documentation on php website.

Comment: Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and look for "Complex (curly) syntax". If this is the answer to your question you should mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
echo "<code><p></code>$_POST[quiz_complete]<code><p></code>";
```

Or

```
echo "<code><p></code>".$_POST['quiz_complete']."<code></p></code>";
```

Actually there is no need of quotes for an array key, if you are using it inside  double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<p>".$_POST['quiz_complete']."</p>";
```